# Adjoint action on universal enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\mathfrak{g} = \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ be a Lie algebra and $U\mathfrak{g}$ be the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. I want to show that if $D\in Z(U\mathfrak{g})$ is in center, then the extended adjoint action $\operatorname{Ad}:G\to \operatorname{End}(U\mathfrak{g})$ satisfies $\operatorname{Ad}(g)D = D$.

This is an exercise 2.2.5 in Bump's automorphic form. The adjoint action $\operatorname{Ad}$ of $G$ on $U\mathfrak{g}$ is defined by
$$
\operatorname{Ad}(g)(x_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes x_{r}) = \operatorname{Ad}(g)x_{1}\otimes \operatorname{Ad}(g)x_{2} \otimes \cdots \otimes \operatorname{Ad}(g)x_{r} 
$$
where $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r \in \mathfrak{g}$; but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: No, $\operatorname{Ad}$ (a group action) does not act through the Leibniz rule. That's what $\operatorname{ad}$ (a Lie algebra action) does. As for $\operatorname{Ad}$, it is given by $\operatorname{Ad}\left(g\right)\left(x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_r\right) = \operatorname{Ad}\left(g\right)\left(x_1\right) \otimes \operatorname{Ad}\left(g\right)\left(x_2\right) \otimes \cdots \otimes \operatorname{Ad}\left(g\right)\left(x_r\right)$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks, I was confusing between those two.

Comment: Also, do you want $G$ to be connected or something like that? I don't see how to prove this otherwise.

Comment: @darijgrinberg We may assume that $G = \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ or $G = \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})^{+}$, where the latter one is a connected component of the first one. I think Bump want to do only for this case.

Comment: Oh. WLOG assume that $g = \exp x$ for some $x \in \mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{gl}_n$. Thus, $\operatorname{Ad}\left(g\right) = \operatorname{Ad}\left(\exp x\right) = \exp\left(\operatorname{ad}_x\right)$, where $\operatorname{ad}_x$ is the (Lie algebra) action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on your space (here, $U\mathfrak{g}$). So it suffices to show that $\operatorname{ad}_x$ sends $Z\left(U\mathfrak{g}\right)$ to zero. But this is clear, since $\operatorname{ad}_x$ is bracketing with $x$.

Comment: @darijgrinbe How can you assume that $g = \exp x$ for some $x$? As I know, the exponential map is not surjective for $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, is it?

Comment: The image of the exponential map is Zariski-dense (as it contains at least an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the identity), but what you want to prove (namely, $\operatorname{Ad}\left(g\right)D = D$ for all $D \in Z\left(U\mathfrak{g}\right)$) is a bunch of polynomial identities in the entries of $g$. Thus we can WLOG assume that $g$ lies in the image of the exponential map.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That seems work. Thank you! Do you know any algebraic geometry free answer?

Comment: This kind of Zariski-density argument is highly elementary (it's just saying that a multivariate polynomial that vanishes on a nonzero ball must vanish identically). It's the use of the exponential map that is bothering me :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Do you know how to prove for $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$? By the above argument, it is enough to check for $\mathrm{diag}(-1, 1, 1, \dots, 1)$, but I don't know if it is easy to check for this case.

Comment: As I said: The Zariski density argument works. Polynomial identities don't distinguish between matrices with positive determinants and matrices with negative determinants.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I do not agree with the argument in the comments; it is not obvious why the adjoint action of $\mathfrak g$ on $U(\mathfrak g)$ vanishes on the center; in general $\operatorname{Ad}_x(D) \neq xD - Dx$.</s>
Below is an alternative proof that I wrote when I mistakenly thought that $\operatorname{Ad}_x(D) \neq xD - Dx$ in general.

Identify $U(\mathfrak g)$ with the algebra of left invariant differential operators on $G$ (connected Lie group) in the standard way. Then you want to show that the operator corresponding to $D \in Z(U(\mathfrak g))$ is invariant under conjugation. Equivalently, right invariant. Now take $X \in \mathfrak g$, $t \in \mathbb R$, $b$ a real analytic function in a neighborhood of $1$ and consider

$$f(g, t) = R_{e^{tX}} D R_{e^{-tX}} b(g) \,,$$
where $R_g$ denotes right translation, for $g, t$ in a small neighborhood $U \times I$ of $(1, 0)$. For fixed $g$ this is real analytic as a function of $t$. We have:

- $f(g, 0) = D b(g)$;
- $\frac d{dt} f(g, 0) =(XD - DX) b(g) = 0$, because $D$ is central;
- $\frac {d^2}{dt^2} f(g, 0) =(X^2D - 2XDX + DX^2) b(g) = 0$;
- $\frac {d^n}{dt^n} f(g, 0) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni X^i D (-X)^{n-i} = DX^n \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni (-1)^i = 0$ for all $n > 0$.

Therefore $f(g, t) = D b(g)$ for all $g \in U$ and $t \in I$.

For $t \in I$, the differential operators $D$ and $R_{e^{tX}} D R_{e^{-tX}}$ coincide in a neighborhood of $1$ and therefore on all of $G$ by left-invariance, so they determine the same element of $U(\mathfrak g)$.

Because $G$ is connected and $I$ can be chosen to be the same for all
bounded $X \in \mathfrak g$, it follows that $R_{g} D R_{g^{-1}} = D$ for all $g \in G$.